# ActiveRecord unable to reconnect when running inside forked/threaded application?

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, resque

Bit of an open-ended question here, so I'll outline the problem first. We have a [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) worker who is supposed to pop data-synchronisation jobs off a queue, the reasons are two-fold, using Cron (and paying Rails environment boot time over-and-over) sucks, and the alternative queues, well Github made a pretty good case against them when they [announced Resque](https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque). Also, the Redis time-series functionality already plays a big part of our infrastructure, where we also shuffle TS data into RRDTool & etc...

**Here's the problem**, with a typical three-hours between jobs (but staff can schedule jobs at any time… hence the queue), the PostgreSQL server goes away. Easy enough to cure, I expected that setting `reconnect: true` under the corresponding environment would ensure that this worked as expected.. I read in a [few](http://cmdrclueless.com/blog/2009/07/06/activerecord-fork-exec-boom/) [places](http://blog.costan.us/2008/11/black-art-of-background-processing-in.html) that `reconnect: true` won't work for applications that use `fork()`. Which, naturally [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) does, to start it's workers… the part I don't understand is why ActiveRecord's reconnect can't work under these circumstances?

I noticed the implementations of `reconnect!` the [MySQL Adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#L203) and the [PostgreSQL Adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L257) in ActiveRecord are different… but either way I would expect the ActiveRecord `reconnect: true` configuration to work.

> The problem seems to be clear enough, when the child process exists, it closes the file handles created by the parent (thus hanging up the connection to the database) - is it possible to close a filehandle in such a way that ActiveRecord doesn't recognise that the connection has been terminated?

There's also, for what it's worth, an [ActiveRecord aware fork()](https://gist.github.com/602983) which I was able to find on Github, as a pastie - it's untested, but I assume it works (haven't tried it with current Rails..)

My question is more, **Why can't the automatic reconnect in AR work if you `fork()`?** (and, latterly - I can't be the only person who is having this problem; I'm chalking it up to using PGSQL with Resque!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While not exactly the answer to "why can't it reconnect", but I think that what can help you is the following code put somewhere in the initialization phase:

```
Resque.after_fork do |job|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
end
```

Update:
Regarding the reconnect - it seems that it's MySQL only feature.
This is how it's used in mysql adapter:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb#L848
As you can see, it uses the underlying driver's reconnect feature.
https://github.com/kwatch/mysql-ruby/blob/master/ext/mysql.c#L923

On the other hand, the postgresql adapter doesn't do anything with regard to `reconnect` option, you can see the https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb

Also, the PostgreSQL site explicitly says that "Forking a process with open libpq connection can lead to unpredictable results" - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-connect.html
And it's also evident that the C driver doesn't provide any reconnect feature.

Comment: Roman, sure - I have the workaround, but I'm specifically looking for the reason why the reconnect: true doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's something about concurrency (activerecord's `allowconcurrency` flag) - and recognising that the first connection is still connected… but I'm at a loss, really.

Comment: Well, by looking at the activerecord code, what I can tell, is that `reconnect` option is not supported for PostgreSQL adapter.

Comment: Roman, can you be more specific, perhaps a link - there was an implementation somewhere that I found… (I'm sure)

Comment: Roman, hardly the (good news!) I was looking for, but worth +50 rep for a well written, and helpful answer, awarded!

Comment: the postgres adapter does indeed have a [reconnect feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4cb47167e747e8f9dc12b0ddaf82bdb68c03e032/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L600-L604), but even if it didn't you could just disconnect and reconnect again.

The reason the disconnect and reconnect is important is because after Resque forks, each fork has a copy of the exact same connection; if they try to use it at the same time, the data will go to a random (forked) process.